# Iterating over a loop till condition is met

Tags: bash, loops, shell, unix

I have a requirement wherein I want my shell script to read a text file having some URLs in it. I want it to hit those with the help of curl one by one. The website can return say either "success" or a "failure".
If in case in first attempt the URL showed a failure then script should  iterate again and trying hitting same URL until it shows a success and thereafter proceed with second URL.

**sample.txt**

```
abc.com
xyz.com
```

I thought of using a `until loop` in `while` `loop` but not sure if it will work. Can someone pls help me out.

As said I thought of using until loop in a while loop but not sure if it will work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using [until](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-until-loop/) loop :

```bash
#!/bin/bash

retry_timer=5
success_timer=120

function check_url_success() {
  local url=$1
  local response=$(curl -s /dev/null "$url")
  if [ "$response" == "success" ]; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}

urls=()
while IFS= read -r url; do
  urls+=("$url")
done < "sample.txt"

for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
  echo "Trying $url..."
  
  until check_url_success "$url"; do
    echo "Failed. Retrying..."
    sleep $retry_timer  # Add a delay before retrying
  done
  echo "Success for $url!"
  sleep $success_timer # Add a delay of 2 min when curl ping succeeded
done
```

Comment: Hi Will, Thanks for replying. 1 doubt. Sleep 5 in your script is before retrying. I want to add 2 mins of sleep once 1st url is success. For that can I add it in function before return 0?                                                                                                                            function check_url_success() {
  local url=$1
  local response=$(curl -s /dev/null "$url")
  if [ "$response" == "success" ]; then          sleep 2m                                                                    
   return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi

Comment: Yes that would works. I personnaly prefer having this logic outside of the function tho. I've edited my answer. Please consider accepting it if it solved your problem.